# how to run App written in swift 2.2 in iPhoneX simulator using 'xcrun simctll install booted' command

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

I have an app which is written in swift 2.2. I would like to execute the .app file iphoneX simulator. App crashes in simulator with error message "codesignature not found"

Comment: Probably not possible since the X sim came out after Swift 4 even –> !compatible.

Comment: Thanks @LinusGeffarth any other way to test the app in iphone-X simulator?

Comment: Update it to Swift 4 and open it in Xcode 9. If, for whichever reason, you don't *want* to update to Swift 4 but stay on 2.2, make a copy of your project, or a branch of your git repo and then revert everything.